# Получение данных из класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

У меня есть класс матрица, который является обёрткой над `double** array` массивом. В нём перегружен `operator(i, j)`, возвращающий `array[i][j]`. При создании других матриц (`B`, `C`) в методах этого класса стоит обращаться непосредственно к `B.array[i][j], C.array[i][j]` или к `B(i, j), C(i, j)`?

Comment: Можно как первым способом (при условии что array в public секции) так и вторым (если оператор в public секции). Точнее если не нарушены условия доступа к классу.

Comment: `B`, `C` это другие классы (производные?) или всего лишь названия переменных класса "матрица"?

Comment: @alexolut объекты этого же класса != *this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методах класса можно, как вы понимаете, и так и эдак.

Я бы сформулировал так - если вы не планируете менять внутреннее представление и не нужны дополнительные действия при обращении к элементам - то можно и прямо как к `.array[i][j]`.

Но, пожалуй, лучше через `operator()` - потому что мало ли что измениться может - например, для отладки вам потребуется в журнал обращения записывать. А простой оператор компилятор будет просто встраивать, так что в эффективности провала не должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

Часто `public` функции обеспечивают дополнительную проверку перед доступом к реальным данным, например, проверка на попадание индексов в допустимый диапазон и генерация исключения, если условие не выполнено. В таких случаях использование этих функций для реализации других операций над классом может приводить к лишним проверкам, которые фактически не нужны, т.к. Вы пишите внутренний (библиотечный) код и знаете, что за границы он выйти не может. Т.е. использование `operator(i, j)` будет излишним, достаточно обращаться явно к `array[i][j]`.